# Apple and Google Pay with React Native and Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, applepay, google-pay

I am trying to set up apple and google pay for an app and I am struggling to find any good documentation on how to do this. I am using React-Native with expo and was wondering if anyone could share any documentation on how to implement this properly.

We already have it set up on our web app and we have the whole payment flow setup already but I am struggling to find any ways to properly implement it into the app without using stripe.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated

I have tried using react-native-payments and also tried to use @stripe/react-native-stripe to see if I could do it without having to use the stripe payment flow. I have also looked into creating a native module but struggled to find anything to help build it

Answer (score 0):

If you plan using custom gateway(like https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us) for the payment and not Stripe or BrainTree(they have their own libs for the RN), take a look at our library which we are using in our project https://github.com/rnw-community/rnw-community/tree/master/packages/react-native-payments

This is a full rewrite of the https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments but in TypeScript and with all recent native code updates.

If you need in-app payments take a look at the https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/get-started